# NGINX Stream Module URL Path to Upstream server?

Tags: nginx

I have the below nginx.conf file which works if I am using dns. However, I wanted to see if there was a way using ssl-pass through to use a single ip that could map to different hosts based on the url path similar to how reverse-proxy's *location* configuration works?

For example, if users were coming in on 10.0.0.3/example1 or 10.0.0.3/example2 it would pass through the ssl request to the appropriate upstream server based on the route...

```
stream {
  map $ssl_preread_server_name $selected_upstream {
    example1.org upstream_1;
    example2.org upstream_2;
  }

  upstream upstream_1 { server 10.0.0.1:443; }
  upstream upstream_2 { server 10.0.0.2:443; }

  server {
    listen 443;
    proxy_pass $selected_upstream;
    ssl_preread on;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to do something with `uri` you have to use `http` server. There is no `uri` in `stream`.

Comment: Can you achieve what I’m asking with http? I don’t believe ssl-passthrough is possible with http.

Comment: Yep. You either have stream or power to parse HTTP. Not both.